# Adding setData to Intent makes widget update on Android

Tags: android-intent, uri, android-pendingintent, appwidgetprovider

I have two widgets and one configuration activity for them. And I had problem with updating widgets. One of AppWidgetProvider classes looked like:

```
public class HolidaysWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];           
        HolidaysBlackWidgetProvider.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetId);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.holidays_appwidget);
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.yearTV, Integer.toString(y));
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.monthTV, Integer.toString(m));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

    }
}
```

And my widget didn't update. But after I added the following code 
my widget began to update:

```
    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, HolidaysWidgetProvider .class);
    configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    configIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("abc" + "://widget/id/"), String.valueOf(appWidgetId)));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, configIntent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pendingIntent);
```

Why adding this code make my widget works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to code in getBroadcast PendingIntent without adding setData are equals. So setting pendingIntent to remoteView can possible put wrong appWidgetId. Setting data is just a hack